# Batch file doesn't insert text from another file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working in Windows 10 and I have text files resulting from another process that I want to edit using a batch file. I've shortened the example, File-1 (shown below with line numbers) for this post. They are all formatted this way, but much longer and with more sections:

```
1 Album 1 - 1982,,,      
2 ('Song 1'),      
3 ('Song 2'),      
4 |===================|      
5 Album 2 - 1978,,,      
6 ('Song 1'),      
7 ('Song 2'),
```

After each line with a string of 3 commas (lines 1 and 5) I want to insert two new lines of text from File-2 before the existing lines in File-1 (lines 2 and 6).

The two lines in File-2 to insert are:

```
NEW LINE 1
NEW LINE 2
```

The desired output would then be:

```
1 Album 1 - 1982,,,      
2 NEW LINE 1
3 NEW LINE 2
4 ('Song 1'),      
5 ('Song 2'),      
6 |===================|      
7 Album 2 - 1978,,,      
8 NEW LINE 1
9 NEW LINE 2
10 ('Song 1'),      
11 ('Song 2'),
```

The closest I've come so far as an experiment is a batch file (that I found and adapted) that finds the 3 commas and replaces them with 3 dots.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=,,,"
set "replace=..."
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (a.txt) do (
    set "word=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "word=!word:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!word!
    endlocal
    )
)
```

Output of the adapted batch file to the screen:

```
1 Album 1 - 1982...      
2 ('Song 1'),      
3 ('Song 2'),      
4 |===================|      
5 Album 2 - 1978...      
6 ('Song 1'),      
7 ('Song 2'),
```

I don't need to change the commas to dots (that was just a test to see if I could make the batch file stop and do something at each instance of a unique string).

My dilemma is that I have searched for hours and can't find how to insert File-2 text in the two proper places of File-1. I've found many explanations on how to insert another file's text at one point or at the end of a first file (using the "type" command), but not at more than one specific point found from the search. Also, File-2 text might be more than two lines in the future, so that is why I want to use an external file to hold it.

All I really want to do right now is:

1. Find a known string (3 commas).
2. Read boilerplate text from a text file and insert it below the lines with the found strings, into the the file sitting in the batch file memory.

For testing, I am echoing this to the screen, but once I am able to get the right output, I can edit the batch file to redirect output to a file. I know there are easier ways of doing this using python or C, but it seems it should be easy to do this way with a small correction.

**UPDATE**

I corrected my batch file per @aschipfl, and made new input files for easier debugging.

a.txt:

```
A LINE 1,,,
A LINE 2
```

b.txt:

```
B LINE 1
B LINE 2
```

I methodically tried three versions of the FIND statement starting with the @aschipfl original but there is no interaction with b.txt.

```
if not "!word!"=="!word:%search%=!" find /V ",,," < "!infile2!" 
if not "!word!"=="!word:%search%=!" < "!infile2!"  find /V ",,,"
if not "!word!"=="!word:%search%=!" find /V ",,," type "!infile2!"
```

The fourth combination **does** interact with b.txt as shown below it.

```
if not "!word!"=="!word:%search%=!" type "!infile2!"  find /V ",,,"
```

```
C:\Users\Pete\Documents\test>test.bat
A LINE 1,,,

b.txt


B LINE 1
B LINE 2The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: find.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: /V.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: ,,,.
A LINE 2

C:\Users\Pete\Documents\test>
```

Now, the batch file reads both lines of both input files but with errors as shown (complete with blank lines, copied directly from screen).

Comment: Concerning your update: I suggested `find /V "" < "!infile2!"` but not `find /V ",,," < "!infile2!"`. The `find` command is not there to find the lines containing `,,,` from file 1; this search is done by the condition `if not "!word!"=="!word:%search%=!"`. Have you really exactly copied the script from my answer? Have you set the variables in the first code section adequately?

Comment: What happens when you replace `find /V "" < "!infile2!"` by `type "!infile2!"`? Have you specified the full paths to both text files? (`%~dp0` just points to the parent directory of the batch script itself)

Comment: Success! Removing section ```find /V "" < "!infile2!"``` and replacing with just ```type "!infile2!"``` makes it work. Maybe not necessary now, but where would I specify the full paths to both text files, in the set commands for each?

Comment: Great, although I don't understand why `find` fails. Perhaps replacing `find /V "" < "!infile2!"` with `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "" < "!infile2!"` helps? Anyway, yes, the full paths need to be specified at the two lines `set "infile?=D:\Full\Path\To\File-?.txt"` on top of the script…

Comment: @aschipfl,Thank you for helping me with this. You have inspired me to increase my knowledge of writing batch files, which I have only dabbled with over the years. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to replace `,,,` by `,,,` + line-break + multi-line text from another file, rather should you, after `echo(!word!`, check whether the current line contains `,,,` by `if not "!word!"=="!word:,,,=!"`, and if so, just type out the other text file by `type "File-2.txt"`, or by `find /V "" < "File-2.txt"` in case its contents may not be terminated with a final line-break:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "infile1=%~dp0File-1.txt"
set "infile2=%~dp0File-2.txt"
set "outfile=con"
set "search=,,,"

> "%outfile%" (
    rem // The strange unquoted option string syntax disables the `eol` character:
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("%infile1%") do (
        set "word=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!word!
        rem // Try to remove search string; if result differs, search string occurred:
        if not "!word!"=="!word:%search%=!" find /V "" < "!infile2!"
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: I'm obviously deficient on understanding batch code commands and syntax, so it's very helpful to study your solution. Your code faithfully reproduces file1 text, but does not insert file2 text. The output is the same if I rem the line with the 'find' command. That leads me to think that there is something wrong with that line (or my file1 example). If I replace the line with  type "!infile2"  then it inserts file2 after every line, as I would expect.

Comment: Hm… that's strange… did you exactly try either `find /V "" < "!infile2!"` (failing) or `type "!infile2!"` (passing)? Are the text files ASCII/ANSI, or is any of them Unicode? If so, try `type "!infile2!" | find /V ""` instead…

Comment: I copied your code right into my batch file. I have tried all three variations that you just listed. None of them make file2 insert. In your comment you typed ```find /V "" < "!infile2!"``` but your original code had ```",,,"``` instead of ``""``. I tried it both ways with the three variations, still no insertion. Sorry to bother you--it's probably something I'm doing wrong. I'm reading and testing further. I don't know if my text files are ASCII/ANSI or Unicode. They are regular Notpad files as far as I know.

Comment: But `type "!infile2!"` works, right? Do you receive any error messages when using `find`? Did you somehow alter the `PATH` system variable? Anyway, to find out the encoding of the text files, open them in Notepad, go to Save As and check the encoding in the file dialogue…

Comment: Thanks, both text files are UTF-8. ```type "!infile2!"``` on a line by itself in the batch file does insert file2 after every line of file1. There are no error messages for ```find``` from the batch file. I ran ```find /V ",,," file1.txt``` at the CL and it returned all lines but the ones with ,,, so that seems to be working.

Comment: Well, I used `find` here to return the whole file with the additional lines, always with a final line-break, but not to filter anything out; `find /V ""` just returns all lines. UTF-8 shouldn't be a problem as there shouldn't be any zero-bytes. I still have no clue why it doesn't work for you, I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas, sorry…

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and I'm sorry. I will continue to work on it and post anything I find. I did notice that if I put ```< "!infile2!"``` outside of the ```IF``` block, I get error, ```The syntax of the command is incorrect.``` but changing it to ```type "!infile2!"``` types the file for each line in file1, if that means anything.

Comment: I added an update section to my post after a little bit of progress.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in a `cmd` `batch-file` would be to use PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows platform, PowerShell is available. This uses a `regex` to insert the content of another file.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    (Get-Content -Path .\afile1.txt) -replace ',,,', ^
        \",,,$([Environment]::NewLine)$(Get-Content -Raw -Path .\afile2.txt)\"
```

Example:

```
C:>type afile1.txt
1 Album 1 - 1982,,,
2 ('Song 1'),
3 ('Song 2'),
4 |===================|
5 Album 2 - 1978,,,
6 ('Song 1'),
7 ('Song 2'),

C:>type afile2.txt
NEW LINE 1
NEW LINE 2

C:>powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
More?     (Get-Content -Path .\afile1.txt) -replace ',,,', ^
More?         \",,,$([Environment]::NewLine)$(Get-Content -Raw -Path .\afile2.txt)\"
1 Album 1 - 1982,,,
NEW LINE 1
NEW LINE 2
2 ('Song 1'),
3 ('Song 2'),
4 |===================|
5 Album 2 - 1978,,,
NEW LINE 1
NEW LINE 2
6 ('Song 1'),
7 ('Song 2'),
```

Comment: Using PowerShell instead of a batch file is probably a more modern approach. I'd like to study its use as soon as I can. Thanks for your post.

Comment: That's fine. Part of the question is whether it would be better to write and maintain and explain three (3) lines of code or twenty (20) lines of code.

Comment: @PeterBuxton, BTW, this is `batch-file` code. Using `powershell.exe` is no different than using `find.exe` or `ipconfig.exe`.

Comment: Your code certainly does the trick! Very interesting, and much shorter than the batch file. Although hard for me to understand the commands and syntax without studying, they look more intuitive than equivalent batch code.

Comment: @ lit, thank you for posting your answer. I would have voted it as the solution except that my posted question was about my batch file. Your script is great for me to study, though.

Comment: That's fine. Of course, you know that this IS a `batch-file`.

Comment: That's very true. I put the line inside a .bat file and it worked perfectly, just like on the CL.